# AWS EMRFS Consistent View enable via SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, emr

Typically emrfs consistency is enabled via emrfs-site.xml
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emrfs-configure-consistent-view.html

Does anyone know if these setting can be accessed via the SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable EMRFS with the Java SDK, an "emrfs-site" configuration needs to be added to the RunJobFlowRequest and the **fs.s3.consistent** property must be set to **true**. Like this:

```
Map<String, String> emrfsProperties = new HashMap<>();
emrfsProperties.put("fs.s3.consistent", "true");

RunJobFlowRequest request = new RunJobFlowRequest()
        ....
        .withServiceRole(SERVICE_ROLE)
        .withJobFlowRole(JOB_FLOW_ROLE)
        .withConfigurations(
                new Configuration().withClassification("yarn-site").withProperties(yarnProperties),
                new Configuration().withClassification("emrfs-site").withProperties(emrfsProperties)
        )
        .withInstances(new JobFlowInstancesConfig()
                .withEc2KeyName(EC2_KEYPAIR)
                ....
```

A full list of EMRFS configuration parameters can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emrfs-configure-consistent-view.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have a full documentation here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/Welcome.html

You need to authorize connection to your AWS first, than you can configure you application to your needs, using API.
Look also here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/CommonParameters.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/EmrConfigurations.html